# Fastest way to process Millions of Rows in SQL Server for a Chart

Tags: sql-server, charts

We are logging realtime data every second to a SQL Server database and we want to generate charts from 10 Million rows or more. At the moment we use something like the code below. The goal is to get at least 1000-2000 values to pass into the chart.

In the query below, we take an avg of every next n'th rows depending on the count of data we pick out from the `LargeTable`. This works fine up to 200.000 selected rows, but then it is way too slow.

```
SELECT 
    AVG(X),
    AVG(Y)
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         X, Y,
         (Id / @AvgCount) AS [Group]
     FROM 
         [LargeTable]
     WHERE 
         Timestmp > @From
         AND Timestmp < @Till) j
GROUP BY
    [Group]
ORDER BY 
    X;
```

Now we tried to select out only every n'th row from `LargeTable` and then make an average of this data to get more performance, but it takes nearly the same time.

```
SELECT 
    X, Y
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         X, Y,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS rownr
     FROM 
         LargeTable
     WHERE 
         Timestmp >= @From
         AND Timestmp <= @Till) a
WHERE 
    a.rownr % (@count / 10000) = 0;
```

It is only pseudo code! We have indexes on all relevant columns.

Are there better and faster ways to get chart data?

Comment: `GROUP BY GROUP` and `(Id / @AvgCount) AS Group` would never have worked. `GROUP` is a reserved word in SQL Server. I *assume* you would have actually properly quoted this (but personally, I suggest you use a different name).

Comment: This is only pseudo code!!!

Comment: It would help if you [paste the execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and then link it in your question. Instructions + FAQ can be found on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think on two approaches to improve the performance of the charts:

1. Trying to improve the performance of the queries.
2. Reducing the amount of data needed to be read.

It's almost impossible for me to improve the performance of the queries without the full DDL and execution plans. So I'm suggesting you to reduce the amount of data to be read.

The key is summarizing groups at a given granularity level as the data comes and storing it in a separate table like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE SummarizedData
(
   int GroupId PRIMARY KEY,
   FromDate datetime,
   ToDate datetime,
   SumX float,
   SumY float,
   GroupCount 
)
```

`IdGroup` should be equals to `Id/100` or `Id/1000` depending on how much granularity you want in groups. With larger groups you get more coarse granularity but more efficient charts.

I'm assuming `LargeTable` `Id` column increases monotonically, so you can store the last `Id` that has been processed in another table called `SummaryProcessExecutions`

You would need a stored procedure `ExecuteSummaryProcess` that:

1. Read `LastProcessedId` from SummaryProcessExecutions
2. Read the Last `Id` on large table and store it into `@NewLastProcessedId` variable
3. Summarize all rows from `LargeTable` with `Id > @LastProcessedId and Id <= @NewLastProcessedId` and store the results into `SummarizedData` table
4. Store `@NewLastProcessedId` variable into `SummaryProcessExecutions` table

You can execute `ExecuteSummaryProcess` stored procedure frequently in a SQL Server Agent Job.

I believe that grouping by date would be a better choice than grouping by Id. It would simplify things. The `SummarizedData` `GroupId` column would not be related to `LargeTable` `Id` and you would not need to update `SummarizedData` rows, you would only need to insert rows.

Comment: We are using now Trigger to create AvgTables depending on the count of Data in the LargeTable. The select now switches the Table that fits best, to be always fast.

Answer (score 0):

Since the time to scan the table increases with the number of rows in it, I assume there is no index on Timestmp column. An index like the one bellow may speed up you query:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Timestmp] ON [LargeTable](Timestmp) INCLUDE(X, Y, Id)
```

Please note, that creation of such index may take significant amount of time, and it will impact your inserts too.

Comment: We have indexes on all relevant columns.

Comment: Then edit your question and post the full DDL of your table, including the indexes, and the execution plan of your slow query.

Comment: Sorry but you didn't understand the question. I don't want to improve the queries i search for other solutions.